# Interior Points and Openness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm new to the topology game and I think I'm understanding the general gist of these questions although I'm having some trouble with understanding some concepts

For set $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: 0 < x^2 + y^2 \le 1 \}$:

a) Find all interior points: would it be correct to say that; $0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1$ is all the points in the interior? since the original subset included the $1,$ and that means it's a boundary point, and  not an interior point

b) For each interior point, find a value for $r$ for which the open ball lies within $S:$ in this case, $r$ denotes the radius right? so legitimate values are $0 < r < 1$

c) Find all boundary points: here all points on the curve $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ are boundary points

And *finally*...

d) is $S$ an open set, is it a closed set? Why or why not?

Here I'd say this is a closed set simply because of the inclusion of the boundary points, but obviously this is a really flimsy answer (along with the rest of my answers) and I was hoping someone could help legitimize them further

Comment: You didn't define $U$ but ask about it in some parts.

Comment: @coffeemath ah sorry! I fixed it now

Comment: " since the original subset included the 1, and that means it's a boundary point, and not an interior point"  Nitpick.  "the 1" is not a point but a collection of all points where $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.  But yes, those point**s** are all boundary points.  !!!BUT!!!! the are not *ALL* the boundary points!  Can you find the others?

Comment: "would it be correct to say that; 0 < x² + y² < 1 is all the points in the interior"  More nitpick.  $0 < x^2 + y^2  < 1$ is an expression and is not points.  $\{(x,y)| 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ is a set of points that satisfy an equation and, yes, these are precisely the interior points of the set S.

Comment: ") is S an open set, is it a closed set? Why or why not?"  Why does it have to be one or the other?  Why can't it be neither or both?

Comment: ") is S an open set, is it a closed set? Why or why not?"  Well, it is not closed because it does not contain all its boundary points.  And it is not open because not all its points are interior.  So it is neither.

Comment: @fleablood hey thanks for the help! Regarding *all* of the boundary points; should I make sure that my expression includes at least one point in the set and one point outside of it (as per the definition of a boundary point)? so  Boundary(S) =  x² + y² ≥ 1

Comment: No.  But $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is also a boundary point. The points where $x^2 + y^2 > 1$ are not boudary points.  The boundary point are $\{(x,y)| x^2 + y^2 = 1\} \cup \{(0,0)\}$. The set $S$ is the uniit disk including the unit circle but not the center point.  That boundary is the unit circle.

Comment: The definition of boundary point does *not* include points in the set (An open set will not contain any boundary points) nor points not in the set (A closed set will contain all boundary points).  Whether the boundary points are in or not in the set or whether the boundary points exist at all will depend on the set.  There is no generalizing.

Comment: The interior of S is $\{(x,y):0<x^{2}+y^{2}<1\}$. Here is the answer to b): suppose $0<a^{2}+b^{2}<1$  let r be a positive number such that $r<1-\sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}}$, and $r<max\{|a|,|b |\}$. If $(x,y)$ lies in the ball of radius r around $(a,b)$ then $\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}} \leq \sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}} + \sqrt {(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}} <\sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}}+r <1$. Also, $|x-a|<r$ so $x \neq 0$ of $r<|a|$. Similarly, $y \neq 0$ if $r<|b|$. Since one of these is true we get ${x^{2}+y^{2} }>0$.

Comment: The defintion of a topology is very broad. A set may be open or closed or both or neither.  The set S is not closed. The phrase "because of the  inclusion of the boundary points" is meaningless. Inclusion of them in what? The boundary points of S do not belong to S. & BTW, that, by itself, is not a reason for a set to be open or closed.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy hey do you mind explaining this proof? are a and b points in this case? and I'm not quite sure I get the middle part with the distance between the two points. Thanks!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy actually I get that r < 1 - sqrt(a^2+b^2) since thats the distance from the origin to the curve

Comment: @dejz, I have taken a point $(a,b)$ in $\{(x,y):0<x^{2}+y^{2}<1\}$ and produced a number r such that the ball of radius r around $(a,b)$ is contained in $\{(x,y):0<x^{2}+y^{2}<1\}$. I hope the proof is now clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not correct to say 0 < $x^2 + y^2$ < 1 is all the interior points.
What is correct to say is that those points (x,y) for which $x^2 + y^2$ < 1 are the interior points.